# Grouping Oracle Pivot results

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM tblCommissionNew
PIVOT(Sum(cost)
for stage in (1,2,3))
where quote_id=207
```

This produces 2 rows, as there are values in Stage 1 and 2.

the current output is

```
COMMISSIONID    CONSUMPTION QUOTE_ID    CALC_DATE   COMM_PAID   STATEMENT_ID    COMM_PAY_DATE   1       2       3
    449         9560        207         06-FEB-17   N           5                               38.24       
    95010       4780        207         30-JUN-17               2472                                            19.12
```

(sorry not sure how to format this correctly)

Is it possible to have these results grouped, so my output could be

```
Quote ID / Stage 1 / Stage 2 / Stage 3
207 / 32.77 / 44.98 / null
```

Comment: Can you show us the original rows? When I just created a table and inserted 2 rows with those values, I get that exact output you wanted.

Comment: @PatrickH Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot is essentially a sort of grouping in itself. The problem here is that you are keeping all the columns such as `COMMISSIONID` which are different on each row. Anything you don't put in the pivot, but you include in the select statement will be grouped on. All you have to do to fix your code is just grab the columns you need first from the table before you pivot. In my example below, I grab QUOTE_ID, STAGE, and COST first and then wrap it around a select statement before pivoting.

```
with tblCommissionNew as
(select 449 COMMISSIONID,9560 CONSUMPTION, 207 quote_id, '06-FEB-17' CALC_DATE, 'N' COMM_PAID, 1 stage, 32.77 cost from dual
    union all
 select 95010, 4780, 207,'30-JUN-17',null, 2, 44.98 from dual
)

select * from(
select QUOTE_ID, STAGE, COST
from tblCommissionNew
)
pivot(sum(cost)
for stage in (1,2,3)) A
where quote_id = 207
```

Output:

```
QUOTE_ID    1       2       3
207         32.77   44.98
```

Answer (score 0):

At first eliminate columns You are not interested in and make pivot:

```
select * 
  from (select quote_id, stage, cost from tblCommissionNew where quote_id = 207) 
  pivot(sum(cost) for stage in (1,2,3))
```